# Unbinding Handlers With off for Buttons In a Div

Tags: jquery

Thought this would be quick and easy. But not so. The scenario I am chasing is to unbind handlers for buttons within a certain div. [This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BJeI9HLjPXsP5L9nDMSd) sets out what I am trying to do.

In that you will see that when either of the first 2 buttons are clicked, a button is added to the NewButtonContainer div and a click event is hooked up.

I thought there was an overload of the off() method which would let me target the children of a chosen element to unbind handlers from.

In that Plunk, the button with text *Unhook Handlers* is the one which I am usinng to try and unbind the handlers:

```
$(function(){

  $('#ClickMe').on('click', function () {

     $('#NewButtonContainer').append('<button id="one">One</button>'); 

     $('#one').on('click', alertScreen);

  });

  $('#ClickMeToo').on('click', function () {

    $('#NewButtonContainer').append('<button id="two">Two</button>'); 

     $('#two').on('click', alertScreen);

  });

  $('#UnHookHandlers').on('click', function () {
    $('body').off('click', '#NewButtonContainer button', alertScreen);
  });

  var alertScreen = function (e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget.id + ' was clicked');
    console.log(e);
  }

});
```

Comment: from the jquery docs on `off()`: The selector string must exactly match the one passed to .on()

Comment: @BrianGlaz Hi Brian. Take a look at the example at the foot of this page http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: not quite the same. In the example, .validator is an event namespace, not a selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
$('#UnHookHandlers').on('click', function () {
    $('#NewButtonContainer button').off('click');
});
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UkmkZdlk3Ku6FHKWTCOG?p=preview)

Comment: That did work, but I thought there was an overload of the off handler which took a selector as an argument. That overload didn't work in my example.